# Bound mismatch error while dealing with generics and inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have following classes and interfaces:

```
public class Entity {}
public interface EntitySet<T extends Entity> {}
```

Now I want to write class implementing `EntitySet` interface and reusing type `T`. I tried following:

```
public class Method1EntitySet<T> implements EntitySet<T extends Entity>{}
```

This gives me error:

> Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

So I tried:

```
public class Method1EntitySet<T> implements EntitySet<T>{}
```

This gives me  error:

> Bound mismatch: The type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type EntitySet

This works:

```
public class Method1EntitySet<T> implements EntitySet{}
```

but it gives me warning:

> EntitySet is a raw type. References to generic type EntitySet should be parameterized.

Also I guess, above `T` is not forced to extend `Entity`.

How should I get this done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type bound should be where the generic type parameter `T` is declared:

```
public class Method1EntitySet<T extends Entity> implements EntitySet<T>{}
```

Comment: and what if I want to specify type of `T` not just `T extends Entity`?

Comment: `public class Method1EntitySet implements EntitySet<ThatSpecificType>{}`. If you're specifying it, you no longer need a type variable.

Comment: @anir In that case you wouldn't be able to use T in the `implements EntitySet<T>` clause.

Comment: Did not get you. Do you mean @AndyTurner is wrong. It seems that what he said is working.

Comment: @anir Maybe I didn't get your comment. If you don't want to use T at all, you can do what Andy suggested.